# What's the keystroke?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I had case today where I was moving some C# code around and my fat fingers inadvertantly bumped some keys. I had a line that read:

```
List<IntSite> siteList = ...
```

and after the keyboard fumble, it was all spaced out like so:

```
List < IntSite > siteList = ...
```

I can't seem to find the shortcut that did that... anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

Auto layout of your code does that. If you, for instance, copy and paste some code, it is laid out automatically for you, provided the code is syntactically correct.

Now, if you hit <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> (Undo) right after such a copy/paste, or right after you hit `;`, `Enter` or `}` or any other key that performs auto-layout, the layout is reverted.

Suppose I take the following snippet:

```
List < int > x = new List < int > () ;
```

and I copy and paste it in Visual Studio, it will look like:

```
List <int> x = new List <int>();
```

If I now hit <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> it will be reverted to the original spacy layout.

Of course, this is a guestimate, but perhaps you inadvertently hit <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd>.

Comment: That does work as you describe, but the original text didn't have the spacey look to it... was just as I originally described.

Comment: @Jon: all-in-all, unless we'd get a full view of your keyboard binding, plugins and add-ons in VS, it'll be hard to find out what caused this. Actually, I find Mir's answer most likely so far...

Comment: Tell me what to post up and I will do so.  I've got no addons installed and the settings I initially setup were the standard C# settings.  I've gone on to customize the colours and a few other minor things.  Just looking now and I don't even see a spacing option for angle brackets, though any parameter or keyword spacing options that could be set, aren't.

Answer (score 1):

If your style is set to insert whitespaces that way, it looks like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>, or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> if you had text selected.

Your fingers might be up to something if they did that on their own!

Comment: No, I don't have that style in effect.  Tried selecting the text and hitting those key combos to no avail.  Wouldn't be the first weird effect I've seen happen by accident.